# How to configure 12.04.2 network without being connected?

Tags: 12.04, networking, network-manager, system-settings

When I use the "Network" tool from the "System Settings" application, it won't let me configure the wired interface unless the cable is attached and "live".

I want to move machines from one network to another and I want to reconfigure them when they are on neither network.  Otherwise, they are on the "wrong" network and the folks in the NOC become concerned.

How can I get the Network tool to let me configure the machines offline?

(I know I can almost do what I want by editing /etc/network/interfaces, but I really prefer to use the Network tool instead.)

Comment: Are you sure you need to statically configure your IP addresses? Are there no DHCP servers on your networks? If not, just open a terminal and type `ifconfig eth0 ipaddr netmask nmask broadcast bcastadddr` where _ipaddr_ is the IP address you wish to give (eg.192.168.1.10), _nmask_ is like 255.255.255.0 , and _bcastaddr_ is IP address with 255 for last number (eg 192.168.1.255). For more information take a look at the ifconfig man page.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Use ifconfig as suggested in the comment above for an ephemeral (disappears on reboot) configuration, or edit /etc/network/interfaces for a persistent (persists across reboots) configuration change.